# Using a singleton and archiving it

Tags: iphone, sdk, singleton, nskeyedarchiver

I have a class where I want to keep persistent settings throughout my app. This class is defined as:

```
@interface Archive : NSCoder <NSCoding> {
    NSString *fromAddress;
    NSString *toAddress;
... more ...
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *fromAddress;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *toAddress;

+ (Archive *)sharedArchive;

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
```

And implemented as:

```
@synthesize fromAddress, toAddress;

+ (Archive *)sharedArchive
{
    if (sharedArchive == nil) {
        NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"mydata"];
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
        sharedArchive = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"myapp"];
        [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    }
    return sharedArchive;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    sharedArchive = [super allocWithZone:NULL];
    return sharedArchive;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return self;
}

- (id)retain
{
    return self;
}

- (NSUInteger)retainCount
{
    return NSUIntegerMax; 
}

- (void)release
{
    //do nothing
}

- (id)autorelease
{
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.fromAddress forKey:@"fromAddress"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.toAddress forKey:@"toAddress"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [self initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    fromAddress = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"fromAddress"] retain];
    toAddress = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"toAddress"] retain];
    return self;
}
```

The application delegate applicationWillTerminate method:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:[Archive sharedArchive] forKey:@"myapp"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:@"myapp" atomically:YES];
}
```

I am new on this concept of archive/unarchive. The problem is that I am not being able to read back from the data file. I get the following error:

-[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL

Could anyone explain what I am doing wrong? Or perhaps a better way to save/restore persistent data. I've looked into the NSUserDefaults class, but I don't think that fits in my case... I am not trying to save user preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to save those two strings? Use NSUserDefaults.

if you don't want to use NSUserDefaults you should provide real paths instead of @"myapp" to writeToFile and readFromFile.

```
NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *path = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myApp"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

and you should also release `NSMutableData *data` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver`

btw, `[writeToFile:atomically:]` returns a BOOL that tells you if the write was successful.

btw2, `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` won't get called often on iOS4 with enabled multitasking.  You should put your save function into `applicationDidEnterBackground:` too.

Comment: Should have ended it at the first sentence. :)

Comment: No, I actually want more than two strings. I only used that example to shorten the code. I am going to try to follow your suggestions and see if I can go further with my goal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@fluchtpunkt got it right; "You only want to save those two strings? Use NSUserDefaults."

Or, more specifically, if:

> have a class where I want to keep
>   persistent settings throughout my app.

Unless you need to persist some significant quantity of data -- large BLOBs or the like -- you should use `NSUserDefaults`.

Relying on archiving and unarchiving at app termination / app launch is rife with potential issues.   Apps don't always get terminated cleanly and unarchiving a bunch of stuff on launch that is used "throughout the app" (i.e. *not* used for app startup) is just going to make your app launch times slower.

If you *do* have some large amount of state that needs to be persisted between launches,  then archiving / unarchiving can certainly work.  However, you should *not* couple the archival to termination;   do you really want the user to lose data when the app is force quit, jettisoned, or the device is hard rebooted (which many users have an unnatural fetish for doing)?